# Yahoo OAuth2 without login screen?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, yahoo

I'm trying to setup a cronjob that will retrieve our Yahoo Gemini Ad Spend stats daily.  I'm able to retrieve this data by following the process for PHP (https://developer.yahoo.com/gemini/guide/custom-reporting.html) - but am forced to use a browser login before Yahoo will authenticate everything.

Obviously this won't work for a cronjob - however I haven't yet seen a solution for skipping this step.

I see in the FAQ that this may not be possible (https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/faq/), but figured others may have come up with a workaround?

Comment: So far, the answer here seems to be that you need to retrieve the token once, and then store it for future use.  I've verified this works in practice, but want to make sure the token does not expire after a certain time before adding this as an answer to my original question.

Comment: How did you get the access token in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is to retrieve the refresh token once via manual approval (through the browser), and then use this refresh token to retrieve the access token each time (through a CURL to https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token).